# UIImagePickerController camera stack the application

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

im using the camera in my app,
the problem is that the application work too slow since the camera comes in.
even after im doin dismiss to the camera the rest of the application is to slow.
locks like the camera still works in background.
is there any way to completely stop the camera?

here is my code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:Nil];

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel");
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [picker resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo");
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    [picker resignFirstResponder];
    UIImage* image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImage* resizeImage = [self fixOrientation:image];
}
```

thanx for help! :)

Comment: capturing Image from Camera it's high resolution might be it's size is 2MB something. so you need to apply some back group thread process for working with image or camera in application.

Comment: ok thanx so lot!,can u post simple code for that please?

Comment: Can you tell us memory and cpu usage before and after capturing image ?

Comment: there is option to see it only on simulation running,and im running device couse im using camera..
any way,is there any way to completely stop the camera?@Ali

Answer (score 5):

In Navigation pane you can check which your thread is consuming memory. focus on that.

Comment: yeah but i dont see it for any reason..can u please post screen shot?

Comment: there is option to see it only on simulation running,and im running device couse im using camera..